How to cut dephased signal at the end with wavedrom?
I'm trying to display waveform of de-phased clock with wavedrom. Each signal (named bit x) have period multplied by 2 and de-phased.
The wavedrom javascript code is given below :
{signal: [
  {name: 'bit 0', wave :'nnnnnnnn'},
  {name: 'bit 1', wave  :'hlhlhlhlh',phase:0.5},
  {name: 'bit 2', wave :'hl.h.l.h'},
  {name: 'bit 3', wave :'hpl..nh.'}
],
 head: {
   text: ['tspan', 
          ['tspan',{class: 'muted h5'}, '0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7  8  9  10 11 12  13 14 15   '],
          ],

 }
}

All signal are printed correctly excepted bit 1 which goes beyond the frame.

Is there a solution to cut this last "period" of bit 1 ?

The solution is to use sub-cycle pulse notation with <> symbols.
One period can be cut into sub signal by surrounding it with <>.
for example, in bit 0 line we can replace one n (negated clock period) by <lh> and got the same render.
For the problematic dephased signal bit 1 we want to display only half period then we just have to add <h and get half period displayed.
{signal: [
  {name: 'bit 0', wave :'n<lh>nnnnnn'},
  {name: 'bit 1', wave  :'hlhlhlhl<h',phase:0.5},
  {name: 'bit 2', wave :'hl.h.l.h'},
  {name: 'bit 3', wave :'hpl..nh.'}
],
 head: {
   text: ['tspan', 
          ['tspan',{class: 'muted h5'}, ' 0   1   2   3   4   5   6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15'],
          ],

 }
}

Image render is following :

